# How to deploy field dependencies using change sets

Tags: deployment, change-set

I want to deploy field dependencies using change sets,How to deploy field dependencies using change sets ?

Answer (score 5):

user10060, it looks like all you need to do is just add the controlling field and the dependent field to the change set, and the field dependencies will be included. If your controlling field is a standard field, then all you need is the dependent field.

#### Example 1: Contact fields, Birth Country and Birth State/Province

Birth State/Province is controlled by Birth Country. To deploy this dependency, I **added both fields** to my change set.

#### Example 2: Account field, Subindustry

Subindustry is a custom field controlled by the standard Industry field. To deploy this dependency, I **added the single Subindustry field** to the change set.

Comment: No problem, @RajSfdc. If you click View Source next to the dependent field after uploading the change set, you can see the metadata that's being deployed and confirm that the dependencies are included in the XML.